# How can I create a seesaw with Farseer Physics Engine?

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

I want to create a seesaw like in this picture:
[image: seesaw]

I created two rectangular bodies, one for the diagonal rectangle and one for the little rectangle in the middle. But I don't know how to connect the two bodies. How can I do that?

How can I create a seesaw with Farseer Physics Engine 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JointFactory.CreateRevoluteJoint`, which creates a `RevoluteJoint` between two bodies.

Note that, by default, bodies connected by joints do not collide with each other (by default, joints have `CollideConnected = false`).

The Farseer samples have a few uses of revolute joints, if you search through them (although none of them are a simple seesaw).

Comment: Thanx. It worked. But how can I delete a joint from the Farseer world if I don't need the joint anymore?

Comment: `World.RemoveJoint`