# How can I move bodies in Farseer, using touch input?

Tags: c#, farseer-physics-engine, windows-phone-8

The player should be able to move a Farseer body with it's fingers. How can I do that? What is the best way to create a Farseer body for the player's finger so that the player can move other Farseer bodies with it? I don't know how to do that.

If the player pushes a body(for example windmill sail) hard with it's finger, then the body should move/rotate faster.

**UPDATE:**

I want to move the body RectangleA1 with my finger/cursor. But something isn't working.
If I press somewhere on the screen and move the cursor/finger a little bit around, then I get very often an error message in this line:

```
world.Step(Math.Min(elapsed, (1f / 60f)));
```

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in FarseerForWindowsPhone.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is wrong? Why am I getting this error message?

My code:

```
    World world;
    Body RectangleA1, RectangleA2;
    Texture2D RectangleA1Sprite, RectangleA2Sprite;
    Body body;
    Fixture fixture;
    bool MouseJointAktiv = false;
    FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Joints.FixedMouseJoint MouseJoint;
    private static float _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio = 100f;

    public static Vector2 ToDisplayUnits(Vector2 simUnits)
    {
        return simUnits * _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio;
    }   

    RectangleA1 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
    RectangleA1.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
    RectangleA1.Mass = 20;
    RectangleA1.Position = new Vector2(4f, 1f);
    RectangleA1.Rotation = 0f;
    RectangleA1.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat5;

    RectangleA2 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 3.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
    RectangleA2.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
    RectangleA2.Mass = 40;
    RectangleA2.Position = new Vector2(4f, 3f);
    RectangleA2.Rotation = 0f;
    RectangleA2.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat10;


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
      float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
      world.Step(Math.Min(elapsed, (1f / 60f)));

      TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
      foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
      {
        if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed))
        {
          fixture = world.TestPoint(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(tl.Position.X, tl.Position.Y))); 
          if (fixture != null)
          {
            body = fixture.Body;
            MouseJoint = new FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Joints.FixedMouseJoint(body, new Vector2(tl.Position.X, tl.Position.Y));
            MouseJoint.MaxForce = 1000 * body.Mass;
            world.AddJoint(MouseJoint);
            body.Awake = true;
            }
          }

          if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved))
          {
            if (MouseJointAktiv == true)
              MouseJoint.WorldAnchorB = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(tl.Position.X, tl.Position.Y));
          }

          if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Released))
          {
            world.RemoveJoint(MouseJoint);
            MouseJoint = null;
            MouseJointAktiv = false;
          }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: I created a FixedMouseJoint for the player's finger but I can't move the windmill's sails with that FixedMouseJoint.

Comment: Not enough info. Also: You can probably make the sails from a single body with multiple fixtures, then use a single revolute joint.

Comment: What is the best way to create a body for the player's finger? Should I use a FixedMouseJoint or should I do that without a joint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation, [again](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/77731/288). This time for `FixedMouseJoint`:

> A mouse joint is used to make a point on a body track a
>   specified world point. This a soft constraint with a maximum
>   force. This allows the constraint to stretch and without
>   applying huge forces.
>
> NOTE: this joint is not documented in the manual because it was
>   developed to be used in the testbed. If you want to learn how to
>   use the mouse joint, look at the testbed.

In other words, a `FixedMouseJoint` attaches an arbitrary point in the world (this is what the "`Fixed`" versions of the joints do), to a point on a body. It is used extensively in the Farseer samples.

(There is no body associated with the user's finger.)

---

Given a `Vector2 position` giving the Farseer world-space position of the user's finger (or mouse cursor), you can create a `FixedMouseJoint` like so:

```
Fixture fixture = world.TestPoint(position); // what was touched?
if(fixture != null)
{
    Body body = fixture.Body;
    mouseJoint = new FixedMouseJoint(body, position);
    mouseJoint.MaxForce = 1000 * body.Mass; // <- tune this for your game
    world.AddJoint(mouseJoint);
    body.Awake = true;
}
```

As usual, when the touch/mouse button comes up, destroy the joint with:

```
world.RemoveJoint(mouseJoint);
mouseJoint = null;
```

Every frame that the joint is active, update the anchor position like so:

```
mouseJoint.WorldAnchorB = position;
```

---

Use a single `RevoluteJoint` for your windmill, using a single body (with multiple fixtures) for your sails.

If the windmill sails are not slowing down as you would like, consider adding a `FrictionJoint` with the same anchor position on each body as the revolute joint.

(If your windmill sails are free-standing (not attached to another body), you could use the `Fixed` versions of these joints.)

Comment: Great answer, fixed mouse joint is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: I always get an error message in this line: body = fixture.Body; An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GameName1.DLL but was not handled in user code. My fixture is always null. How should I create the fixture in this case? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: That means that `World.TestPoint` is returning null - because the user is not actually touching a fixture in the world. So simply don't create a joint in that case. (I've updated my code to reflect this.)

Comment: If I press somewhere on the screen and move the cursor/finger a little bit around, then I get very often an error message.

Comment: @Homer_Simpson Well, debug it!

Comment: OK. It works now.